# Japanese gairaigo database

Tags: data-request, japanese, translation

The Japanese language has many terms imported from foreign languages, for instance `タワー` (pronounced "tawaa") means (and comes from) `Tower`.

I am looking for a database of such term and the original word they come from. Example:

```
タワー , Tower
ビルディング , Building
… , …
```

It should not include [wasei-eigo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasei-eigo) and terms whose meaning in Japanese does not match at all the meaning in the original language.

## Context

I wrote a [tool to transliterate Japanese place/business names to Latin characters](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/jakaroma), it works well except it could do better for garaigo terms, for instance now it transliterates `六本木ヒルズ森タワー` to `Roppongi Hiruzu Mori Tawa-`. If I find the database described in this question I could improve that to `Roppongi Hills Mori Tower` which would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

I know someone made a converter http://www.sljfaq.org/cgi/k2e.cgi that convert kana into possible foreign word, but it is a multi match system that each kana are given multiple possible corresponding answer. It probably doesn't match your need due to the too many outcome and is not open, but might be it's worth to further investigate about it. Contact is on the webpage and there's also a google group for it at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sljfaqorg .

[image: Example]